# PDFKit - Undefined Method 'Scan" Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, pdfkit

Getting this error:

```
NoMethodError in AwardsController#certificate 
undefined method `scan' for #<Array:0x0000000354bd40>
```

Gemfile:

```
gem 'pdfkit'
```

Ran bundle install

application.rb:

```
require 'pdfkit'
config.middleware.use "PDFKit::Middleware"
```

routes.rb:

```
match 'awards/certificate/:id' => 'awards#certificate', :as => :certificate, :via => :get
```

awards_controller:

```
def certificate
    @award = Award.find(params[:id])
    html = render :layout => false 
    kit = PDFKit.new(html, :page_size => 'Letter')
    kit.stylesheets << RAILS_ROOT + '/public/stylesheets/scaffold.css'
    send_data(kit.to_pdf, :filename => "#{@award.nominee_fullname Certificate}", :type => 'application/pdf')
  end
```

rake middleware:

```
use PDFKit::Middleware
```

rake routes:

```
certificate GET    /awards/certificate/:id(.:format)     awards#certificate
```

If I put .pdf at the end of the URL, I get this:

```
Routing Error

No route matches [GET] "/highfive/awards/certificate/51"
```

Anyone know wth I'm doing wrong?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `render_to_string` instead of `render`